# Повторить настройки предыдущего проекта Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse

Где-нибудь раз в два-три месяца начинаю новый проектик на С++ под Eclipse. И мне раз за разом приходиться новый проект настраивать на C++11. Это может быть просто какой-нибудь тестовый проект. Приходится вспоминать, что же там было и заново искать, как это настроить. Как упростить данную процедуру?

Comment: Посмотрите, пожалуйста, в справке http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FprojectTemplateEngine%2FHowtoregistertemplates.html